# Methods for managing loose wires during prototyping

Tags: cables, led-strip, prototyping, adhesives

I have quite a few switches and other somewhat bulky components to fit into a box for a build, which will require some careful management of the free space within to avoid other wires getting pinched, or tugged on.

Is there a material that would reliably hold 18-22awg wire to a plastic chassis semi-permanently? (ABS or PVC, depending on location, in case it makes a difference). Would simple Scotch tape, or typical electrical tape hold up in a bit of heat? LED strips within the chassis can get it pretty warm. Would a tacky putty work, or would the warmth turn it into a gooey mess?

Comment: Why don't you stick some tape on the chassis and blow it with a heat gun and see what happens?

Comment: Lost my old one in a recent flood, but I'm probably overdue for a replacement. I'll give it a try.

Comment: In aircraft wiring, waxed nylon string is used to stitch or bond groups of wire together to improve on strength to hold its position. It is like heavy dental floss.

Comment: @Tony I looked into this after reading your comment, and I like the idea. I have no places to tie the bindings down to hold the wires where I'll need them, but keeping them bunched without zip-ties would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have room, you can use [this](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/522210000.pdf) sort of self-adhesive cable holder:

[image]

Comment: I'd actually found quite a few of these while rummaging through some spare components, but unfortunately, no, I don't have the real estate within the unit to fit them. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

After powering the project for a while and keeping the LEDs lit with various adhesive tapes inside, I've determined that standard, plastic-backed black electrical tape holds up. The inside of the box does not heat up enough to weaken the adhesive noticably.

Big ol' bundle of electrical tape - and, now, some waxed nylon cord - it is!

Comment: Kapton tape is much better than electrical tape.

Comment: @D Duck I've never heard of it, before. Is it something that can be found at a big box store, or will I need to go hunting online? Is Kapton a type, or brand name?

Comment: Kapton is a polyimide film - it's that distinctive yellow/orange film / tape that you see inside phones. An internet search will result in a plethora of sources. More expensive than black tape, but longer lasting and without all the sticky adhesive.

Comment: @D Duck Figured out through such searches that nowhere local carries any. This is fine, it just means a delay waiting for orders. :p